# How to catch gesture from its child in GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, dart

In this part of code only `doSthElse()` is being called.

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: doSth,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: doSthElse,
      )
)
```

If I set `null` instead of `doSthElse`, then `doSth` is called when `onTap` occurs.
Is there any way to call both methods on the same tap action?

Comment: Does the `AbsorbPointer` widget help?

Comment: I was thinking about that too @Benjamin, but he requested again in his question to call both methods when a single click event happens.

Comment: hope this solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77782740/8438750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I figured it out. I merged @Benjamin and @Locked answers and got this:

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
            doSth();
            widget.button.onPressed();
      },         
      child: AbsorbPointer(
            child: widget.button, 
            absorbing: true,
      ),
)
```

`widget` is `StatefulWidget` and code above is in its state build method.

Comment: Sure thing, but need to wait 2 days though. Thanks once again.