# How to wrap GestureDetector with another GestureDetector and get events everywhere

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

If I have a `GestureDetector` that have an internal `GestureDetector` how can I setup it so that both detectors receive the click event?

You can see the running code here:
https://dartpad.dev/37807a51a48e52eda81c24cf67260c33

```dart
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print("Log 1"),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => print("Log 2"),
        child: Text("CLICK ME")
      )
);
```

- Every time I click the text it prints `Log 2`.
- I already tried setting `HitTestBehavior.traslucent` and all of them but got no success.
- I want it to print `Log 1` and `Log 2`

Comment: Found this with the google: https://gist.github.com/Nash0x7E2/08acca529096d93f3df0f60f9c034056

Comment: @Gregg it works!!! Do you want to put the answer as the answer, so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
        gestures: {
          AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
              AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
            (AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
              instance..onEnd = (_) => print("test1");
            },
          )
        },
        child: RawGestureDetector(
          gestures: {
            AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
              () => AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
              (AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
                instance..onEnd = (_) => print("test2");
              },
            )
          },
          child: Container(color: Colors.red),
        ));
  }
}

class AllowMultipleVerticalDragGestureRecognizer extends VerticalDragGestureRecognizer{
  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    acceptGesture(pointer);
  }
}
```

Credit: https://gist.github.com/Nash0x7E2/08acca529096d93f3df0f60f9c034056

Answer (score 1):

There is also a simpler way to achieve this by using `Listener`:

```
Listener(
 onPointerDown: (event) => print("Log 1"),
 child: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => print("Log 2"),
  child: Text("CLICK ME"),
 ),
);
```

Hope this solves this issue!