# Is it possible to pass a tap event to multiple widgets at the same time in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I tap a widget, I want that widget and the widget behind it to recognize my tap at the same time. But what happens is only the widget at forefront recognizes the tap.

I've tried this in several ways, with a simple parent/child relation with all the combinations of `HitTestBehavior`:

```dart
Center(
  child: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () => print('red'),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () => print('green'),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Also tried using a `Stack`. Again, with all possible behaviors:

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => print('red'),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: () => print('green'),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

I know I can simply use a mutual function for both of the detectors, but the main reason I want to achieve this is when using nested widgets, it is required to add unnecessary implementations to access that functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap GestureDetector with another GestureDetector and get events everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66285602/how-to-wrap-gesturedetector-with-another-gesturedetector-and-get-events-everywhe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onPanDown`

```dart
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () => print('green'),//doesnt work
  onPanDown: (details) => print('tdgreen'),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  ),
),
```

You can check [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45253#issuecomment-564093260) for more.

Comment: thank you, it worked but it seems `onPanDown` is being triggered as soon as it's pressed, not quite the behavior i wanted. but `onPanEnd` works just like `onTap` (when the pointer released). have a nice day.

Comment: depends on your need, btw onPanEnd  will call end of the event. if you like some delay , Future.delay will help.