# Detect touches inside a pdfviewer.. Force detect a touch when a widget handles its own touch events

Tags: flutter, pdf, touch, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

I'm using syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer which has its own 'gesture event handler', and I wanted to detect when a user tap on screen to show/hide some buttons.

**The problem is that any touch inside the pdf page isn't detected by** `GestureDetector`

**So** *is there a way to force detect touches inside pdf widget or something??*

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                print('click event');
              },
    
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  PdfViewer(filePath: path, pdfKey: _pdfViewerKey, controller: controller,),
    
                  TopBar(title: basename(path)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred to [this answer](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/179682/on-tap-event) from *Syncfusion team* which implies the use of `RawGestureDetector`, but I noticed a delay when detecting taps; also when I performed (pinch to zoom) gesture, an error occurs 90% of the time.

Then I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73511998/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-tap-event-to-multiple-widgets-at-the-same-time-in-flutt/73512027#73512027) in which they used a `GestureDetector` with `onPanDown` attribute, but the problem is that it detects any touch before the user left up his finger, and that includs swipes.

### **What I came up with:**

1- I put an **empty** `Container` with the size of the screen with a `GestureDetector` *on top* of my PdfView.

2- Normally using a `GestureDetector` wouldn't work on an empty `Container` *so I had* to use the `HitTestBehavior.translucent` attribute.

3- You can't use a translucid color because that would prevent any touch event on the PdfView.

```
Stack(

     children: [
        PdfViewer(),

        GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, //to listen for tap events on an empty container

              onTap: () => print("Handle Tap event!!"),

              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
            )

     ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

We have prepared a workaround to retrieve the tapped coordinates when the user taps the SfPdfViewer, which can be downloaded from the following link,
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/tapped_position-721291336
Please find the workflow for this example application below,

We have used the **TapGestureRecoginzer** to catch the tap action and **onTapDown** callback we have called **_getPdfCoordinates()** method, it has the logic to return the tapped location coordinates relative to the PDF page.